# Use of Cauchy general principle of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Question: Prove the convergence of sequence using Cauchy general principle of convergence.
$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + . . + \frac{1}{n!}.$$

**My attempt:**

$$ | s_2 - s_1 | = \frac{1}{2!} \\
| s_3 - s_2 | = \frac{1}{3!}\;\;\;\;\text{i.e.}\;\;\;\;| s_2 - s_1 | \leq| s_2 - s_1 | \\
| s_4 - s_3 | = \frac{1}{4!}\;\;\;\;\text{i.e.}\;\;\;\;| s_4 - s_3 | \leq | s_2 - s_1 | \\
\text{Finally,}\;\;\;\;| s_{n+1} - s_n | \leq | s_2 - s_1| $$
Now for $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n\geq m$ such that
$$ | s_n - s_m | = | (s_n - s_{n-1}) + ( s_{n-1} - s_{n-2}) + \cdots  + (s_{m+1} - s_m) |$$ or
$$ \leq |s_n - s_{n-1}| + |s_{n-1} - s_{n-2}| + \cdots  + |s_{m+1} - s_m|$$or
$$ \leq |s_n - s_{n-1}| + |s_{n-1} - s_{n-2}| + \cdots  + |s_{m+1} - s_m|$$ or
$$ 
\leq |s_2 - s_1| + |s_2 - s_1| + \cdots  + |s_2 - s_1|$$or
$$ \leq \frac{n-m}{2}.$$
**Challenge:** From here on I am unable to proceed and always getting stuck in assuming values for $\epsilon$ and $n$. This is happening for similar questions, too. Please help me to the correct frame of thinking for such questions, and also help in completing above question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m>n$, then\begin{align}s_m-s_n&=\frac1{(n+1)!}+\frac1{(n+2)!}+\cdots+\frac1{m!}\\&=\frac1{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac1{n+2}+\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}+\cdots+\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)\cdots m}\right)\\&\leqslant\frac1{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac1{n+2}+\frac1{(n+2)^2}+\cdots\right)\\&=\frac1{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac1{n+2}}\\&=\frac{n+2}{(n+1)\times(n+1)!}.\end{align}Now, take $\varepsilon>0$. Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+2}{(n+1)\times(n+1)!}=0,$$ there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\frac{n+2}{(n+1)\times(n+1)!}<\varepsilon.$$So, if $m,n\geqslant N$, you hvae three possibilities:

- $m=n$: then $|s_m-s_n|=0<\varepsilon$;
- $m>n$: then $0<s_m-s_n<\frac{n+2}{(n+1)\times(n+1)!}<\varepsilon$;
- $m>n$: then $0<s_n-s_m<\frac{m+2}{(m+1)\times(m+1)!}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for reply, The ratio test and other methods we have studied in later chapters , this solution is very lucid. But can we conclude like this without defining $\epsilon$ and n.

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: Thank you.As I am having trouble in concluding the question, please look at this too- for sequence {1 - 1/2 +1/3-1/4...... $(-1)^{n-1} / n$}. $$ | s_n - s_m| \leq log 2$$, so can we end the question by saying- for each $\epsilon \geq log 2 \geq 0$ there exist a positive integer M $ \geq \epsilon$ such that for n , m $\geq$ M,  $|s_n- s_m| \leq \epsilon$ and hence its convergent

Comment: That doesn't work for *every* $\varepsilon>0$, only for those which are greater than $\log2$.